# valgrind massif heap profiler no detailed snapshot view - how do you zoom in/out?

Tags: ubuntu, valgrind, massif

So I am trying to see my heap memory usage for my c++ program in Ubuntu 18

I have run it using:

`valgrind --tool=massif --smc-check=all ./myprogram`

I get quite a large output, which is ok. I view it using massif-visualizer.

I get a pretty graph and all that. But I want to look in detail at the end of my program to see how well it shutsdown. But I can't seem to zoom in on the graph view and I see no option to do this.

The manpage([here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/massif-visualizer.1.html)) says this:

> Massif  generates  a few detailed snapshots that essentially make up
>   the tree. If you want
>          to get an overview in a more comfortable way than the simple tree view, switch over to the
>          detailed  snapshot tab and see the tree visualized as a call graph. Zoom in, zoom out, use
>          the birds eye view and see what contributes to a given snapshot. Note that function  calls
>          with the same memory cost are grouped to easily find the interesting parts.

But I can't see an option to "`switch over to the detailed  snapshot tab`"... does anyone else know how to do that?

Ubuntu 18

massif-visualizer 0.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of massif visualiser, you might use kcachegrind to visualise the memory
using the new 'xtree feature' that appeared in valgrind 3.13.

Here is an extract of valgrind --help:

```
  user options for Valgrind tools that replace malloc:
    --alignment=<number>      set minimum alignment of heap allocations [16]
    --redzone-size=<number>   set minimum size of redzones added before/after
                              heap blocks (in bytes). [16]
    --xtree-memory=none|allocs|full   profile heap memory in an xtree [none]
                              and produces a report at the end of the execution
                              none: no profiling, allocs: current allocated
                              size/blocks, full: profile current and cumulative
                              allocated size/blocks and freed size/blocks.
    --xtree-memory-file=<file>   xtree memory report file [xtmemory.kcg.%p]
```

See http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.xtree
for more information.

Comment: Thanks phd, I tried this and read the doc. But I could not quite see how to use kcachegrind to visualise the heap memory easily. I could look at each "line" to see what was happening - but that would take years to go through!... can you expand a little on how to visualise memory over time and then "zoom" in to look at specific increase/decreases? ... plus 1 for now though as I did not know about xree :)

Comment: In your question, you indicate "But I want to look in detail at the end of my program". For this, you can e.g. use massif but in addition add --xtree-memory=full. With this option, you will get an xtree memory file that you can load in kcachegrind. You can then use e.g. the graph view of kcachegrind to scan the function call sequence that still have a lot of memory allocated at shutdown. If you want to search for call sequences that have allocated a lot of memory that was freed, you switch to the 'total allocated' event in kcachegrind.

Comment: You might also be interested in looking at the fosdem presentation/slides at https://archive.fosdem.org/2017/schedule/event/valgrind_features.   For what concerns having the massif detailed snapshots or peak snapshots in kcachegrind format: such feature is not available (yet?) in massif.

Comment: Thanks for very much the info : )